# Keep service while phone is alive

Tags: android

I have broadcast receiver that activates on phone boot

```
public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, MyService.class);
        arg0.startService(intent);
        Log.i("Autostart", "started");
    }
}
```

The service is very simple it just keeps registered an broadcast receiver that can be only registered by code and not from manifest

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    ScreenOffReceiver actionScreenOffReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {

        try {
            IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentfilter.addAction(Intent.MY_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(actionScreenOffReceiver = new ScreenOffReceiver(),
                    intentfilter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the app get closed, for example with call of finish() on some activity, then the service just dies.

How can I keep the service running till the phone is turned on

what is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an `BroadcastReceiver` just add this code in your `Service`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

*Source: [Service | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29)*